# iphone xml parsing issue

Tags: iphone, xml, xcode, xml-parsing

I am trying to get XML parsing done for my iphone app. But am stuck with an error:

```
XMLParser *xParser = [[XMLParser alloc] initWithContentsofURL:@" http://myimgurl.com/iphoneappimages.xml";];

[xParser setParseItem:@"image"];

[xParser startParse]; 

NSArray *arrItems = [xParser objectForKey:@"image"];
```

Getting the error - `'XMLParser' may not respond to '-objectForKey:'` - on the last line.

What is wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: what is XMLParser class?

Comment: `objectForKey` is a method that's normally from the `NSDictionary` family. If `XMLParser` isn't a descendant of it then you're going to have trouble. Give us a little more info and I think we can have this resolved pretty quickly :)

Comment: `code`@interface XMLParser : NSObject<NSXMLParserDelegate> {
 NSMutableDictionary *dicStories;
 NSMutableDictionary *dicDummy;
 NSMutableString *strBuff;
 NSXMLParser *xmlParser;
 NSString *parseItem;
}

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSMutableDictionary *dicStories;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *parseItem;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSXMLParser *xmlParser;

-(id)initWithFileName:(NSString *)strFileName;
-(id)initWithContentsofURL:(NSString*)strURL;
-(void)startParse;

@end`code`

- The XMLParser interface is as above

Answer (score 1):

From apple's class reference:

> An NSXMLParser notifies its delegate
>   about the items (elements, attributes,
>   CDATA blocks, comments, and so on)
>   that it encounters as it processes an
>   XML document. It does not itself do
>   anything with those parsed items
>   except report them.

You need to make your class an NSXMLParserDelegate and use these (and other) delegate methods:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
```